# Properly rendering a task list using onSnapshot after adding/deleting items from the list

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

## What I am making

I am making a simple task organization app using vue and firestore.
I made 5 functionalities so far.

1. Login
2. SignUp
3. Get and render a task list
4. Add / delete a task
5. [Not working!] Rendering any changes in list of tasks in realtime

#### Not working properly

It gets and loads array data from firestore and renders in realtime but, doesn't render properly

---

## Issue detail

this issue becomes visible when it updates the list due to adding or deleting a task from the list.

Please check the image to get the clearer image of the issue.

[Screenshots of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOROR.jpg)

---

## What I tried

- Solve by refreshing the page but losing the point of having a realtime update.
- Saw somewhere that set Vue () / new Vue () would solve, but did not. (Or more like I am too beginner to understand this concept to apply it...)

Most possibly I am not comprehending what's the real issue behind... So it would be great if anyone could point me out what's the real issue. So look forward to hear your ideas!

## Code

There are mainly two files responsible for rendering list of tasks.

1. projectList.vue : where I get and load array datas and render the list of tasks
2. projectCard.vue : where I insert data of each tasks for projectList.vue to create the list.

(I will also add script for adding project; addProject.js just in case.)

**projectList.vue : Get, load, render list of tasks**

```
<template>
  <div class="projectList">
    <button class="home-buttons" @click="newProject">Add project</button>
    <div v-if="createNew">
      <projectAdd/>
    </div>
    <div v-show="loading">
      <Loader/>
    </div>
    <div v-show="!loading">

      <!--03 Pass array data to projectCard.vue then render the list of entries-->
      <projectCard v-for="project in projects" :key="project.id" :project="project"/>

    </div>
    <p v-show="noproject">There is no project</p>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import firebase from '@/firebase/firestore';
import Loader from '@/components/loading.vue';
import projectCard from '@/components/projectCard.vue';
import projectAdd from '@/components/addProject.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    projectCard,
    Loader,
    projectAdd,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      userid: this.$route.params.userId,

      //02 Put array data here
      projects: [],

      loading: true,
      createNew: false,
    };
  },
  created() {
    //01　Get datas in realtime then pass an array data to projects: []
    const db = firebase.firestore()
    .collection('user')
    .doc(this.userid) //$route.params.userId
    .collection('projects')
    .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc');
    db
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            this.projects.push(doc.data());
        });
        if (this.projects.length >= 0) {
          this.loading = false;
        } else if (this.projects.length <= 0) {
          this.loading = false;
        }
      });
  },
  methods: {
    newProject() {
      if (this.createNew !== true) {
        this.createNew = true;
      } else {
        this.createNew = false;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**projectCard.vue : Insert each data in array**

```
<template>
  <div class="projectCard">
    <div class="user-list">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column is-8">
          <h3>{{ project.projectname }}</h3>
          <p>{{ project.slug }}</p>
          <p>Why : {{ project.why }}</p>
          <p>{{ project.phase }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-4 right">
          <router-link class="button is-primary" :to="{ name: 'viewproject', params: { projectId: project.slug }}">
            Find out more!
          </router-link>
          <button @click="deleteProject"> Delete </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from '@/firebase/firestore';

export default {
  name: 'ProjectCard',
  props: {
    // Holds array data from parent-component; projectList.vue
    project: Object,
  },
  methods: {
    // Delete a task
    deleteProject() {
    firebase.firestore().collection('user').doc(this.project.userId)
    .collection('projects')
    .where('slug', '==', this.project.slug)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc => {
      console.log(doc.data().slug);
      doc.ref.delete();
      alert('You have deleted the project!' + doc.data().slug);
      })) 
    })
    },
  },

};

</script>
```

---

**addProject.js : Add Task (this functionality is accessible from another component rendered in projectList.vue)**

```
import firebase from '@/firebase/firestore';

export default {
  addProject(createdAt, userId,projectname,why,phase){
    const db = firebase.firestore().collection("user")
    .doc(userId).collection("projects"); // "Project"という名前のコレクションへの参照を作成
    db.add({
      createdAt: createdAt,
      userId: userId,
      projectname: projectname,
      why: why,
      phase: phase,
      slug: this.generateUUID(),
    })
      .then(function (docRef) {
        console.log('Document written with ID: ', docRef.id);
        alert('Well done! You have created a new project!');
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('Error adding document: ', error);
      });
  },
  generateUUID() {
    let d = new Date().getTime();
    let uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
      let r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
      d = Math.floor(d / 16);
      return (c === 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
  },
};
```

Thank you for spending your valuable time to read this far and to help me out of this issue!
Looking forward to hear some ideas from you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because each time the listener is triggered you receive the **entire** result of your query, i.e. all the docs corresponding to it.

You basically have two options:

### Option 1: Re-initialize your array

Re-initialize your array before populating it, as follows:

```
  created() {

    const db = firebase.firestore()
    .collection('user')
    .doc(this.userid) //$route.params.userId
    .collection('projects')
    .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc');

    this.projects = [];  <-- See here

    db
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            this.projects.push(doc.data());
        });
        if (this.projects.length >= 0) {
          this.loading = false;
        } else if (this.projects.length <= 0) {
          this.loading = false;
        }
      });
  },
```

### Option 2: Listen to actual changes

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots), you can detect "the **actual changes** to query results **between query snapshots**".

For example, you could only handle the additions, as follows:

```
db
  .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        if (change.type === "added") {
            this.projects.push(change.doc.data());
        }
        //....
    });
    //....
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works perfectly now!
By the way, does sorting like, `orderBy()`, works inside of `if(change.type === "added"){}` ?? Currently the new added data always added to the bottom of the list, while I want the new item added on the very first row in the list.

Thanks for your ideas and help!

Comment: @YuukiTeraoka You may use `unshift` instead of `push`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift